# how to filter after populated mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need to filter my business document according to a type of service.

```
var BusinessSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    slug: String,
    service: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Service'}],
    owner: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Business', BusinessSchema);
```

And Schema service is:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ServiceSchema =  Schema({
    name: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Service', ServiceSchema);
```

Of this array of businesses would only need those that have within its services the "Service A" for example.

```
"business": [
        {
            "_id": "594957df4e195d2500324726",
            "owner": "59482e80d4df7208503154b8",
            "slug": "Almacene2s",
            "name": "Almacene2s",
            "__v": 0,
            "service": [
                {
                    "_id": "594ab160778ae82c44af3a78",
                    "name": "Service C",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "594ab1be778ae82c44af3a7a",
                    "name": "Service D",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ], 

        },
        {
            "_id": "5948483e6bcc1f2788b09145",
            "owner": "59482e80d4df7208503154b8",
            "slug": "guaranda-2",
            "name": "Guaranda Fig",

            "service": [
                {
                    "_id": "594ab160778ae82c44af3a78",
                    "name": "Service A",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "594ab1be778ae82c44af3a7a",
                    "name": "Service B",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ],   

        }
]
```

In this case the result I want to get is:

```
{
            "_id": "5948483e6bcc1f2788b09145",
            "owner": "59482e80d4df7208503154b8",
            "slug": "guaranda-2",
            "name": "Guaranda Fig",

            "service": [
                {
                    "_id": "594ab160778ae82c44af3a78",
                    "name": "Service A",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "594ab1be778ae82c44af3a7a",
                    "name": "Service B",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ],   

        }
```

It is very important for me to be able to carry out this search, because the system will allow the user to choose as a filter the business that has the desired service.

It's my first project on nodejs + mongodb and I would like your help before continuing on. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), here's what you can achieve:

```
Service.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "name": "Service A"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "business",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "service",
            as: "businesses"
        }
    }
], function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

In this aggregation pipeline, you first match and find service documents with name "Service A". Then lookup in `service` array of business documents for matching ones and place them in `businesses` field. The result will look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "594af96883ab76db8ecd021b",
    "name" : "Service A",
    "businesses" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "594af9a683ab76db8ecd0225",
            "slug" : "Almacene2s",
            "owner" : "59482e80d4df7208503154b8",
            "name" : "Almacene2s",
            "service" : [ 
                "594af96883ab76db8ecd021b", 
                "594af96883ab76db8ecd021d"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```